# Why are these js object literals being frozen?

Tags: javascript

I've run into an issue where on Firefox and Chrome, at least, properties of object literals I've created are being frozen. I'm including a screenshot of the output of the below code snippet since I'm having a hard time believing this is true. I must have something on my end causing this, or I just really don't understand JavaScript.

[image]

```js
let b = { foo: { bar: 2 }, baz: 9 };

console.log("b:", Object.isFrozen(b));
console.log("foo:", Object.isFrozen(b.foo));
console.log("foo.bar:", Object.isFrozen(b.foo.bar));
console.log("baz:", Object.isFrozen(b.foo.baz));
```

Comment: ‍♂️ This was a red herring. My issue is that I'm getting a `TypeError: "b.baz" is read-only` error in my project. While creating a MCVE, I thought this was the issue since `isFrozen` returns true for primitives. However, changing the snippet to mutate `b.baz` doesn't reproduce my issue here. I will have to create another question once I can make a proper MCVE.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not that any of the objects are frozen - they aren't. It's that the properties you're referring to are **primitives**, not objects.

Primitives are immutable. `Object.isFrozen` returns `true` for them.

As [the specification says](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-object.isfrozen):

> If Type(O) is not Object, return true.

Comment: Ok, my issue seems to be elsewhere, and this is a red herring. When I try to modify `b.baz`, I get an error in FF: `TypeError: "baz" is read-only`. In my attempt to make a mcve, I thought I had found the issue.

Comment: @Nick - `b.foo.baz` is definitely not read-only in your example. How are you getting this object?

Comment: I'm using a few libraries, I'll have to form another question once I narrow it down.

Answer (score 3):

This is because you are invoking [`Object.isFrozen`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/isFrozen#non-object_coercion) on a primitive.

> In ES2015, a non-object argument will be treated as if it was a frozen ordinary object, return true.

This is more simply reproduced below:

```js
console.log(Object.isFrozen(2));
```